# Can I travel to the USA with an ESTA while my OPT application is pending?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, f1-visas, austrian-citizens

I from Austria and studied in the USA for a while. After graduating I applied for post-completion [Optional Practical Training](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/practical-training) authorization (OPT). However, this is where my problem starts. I had to leave the country right afterwards. I know that this was not a good idea but I had to have surgery in my home country. Besides I had no place to stay in the USA and no money and obviously I was not allowed to work. My OPT application is now being processed. I wonder if can I reenter the USA with an ESTA before I get my EAD card for the OPT?

Answer (score 3):

If you enter the USA on any status other that your F-1 student visa (such as your ESTA), there is a high chance that your SEVIS record and F-1 student status will be terminated. This will prevent you from being able to work on your OPT once it is approved.

The most simple next step is to wait until your OPT is approved and have your university or a trusted friend mail your new EAD to you in Austria. If you are unable to wait in Austria, you should contact the international student center of your school/university to get their advice on entering the US after your program completion date while you are still waiting to receive your EAD.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I was also thinking to have a friend mail me the documents to me but I was told that sending documents isnt allowed. I’d have to look into that.

Comment: @Iris: There is no law prohibiting you from asking a friend to mail the EAD to you in Austria. If you EAD is being mailed to your university, your university may have a policy against releasing your EAD to any person other than yourself. I have just had my own EAD mailed to me outside the US by my US university. In any case, talk to your university about your situation – they sponsored your original F-1 visa and it is their responsibility to help you to maintain compliance with the regulations while you are under their sponsorship.

Comment: may I ask where it was send to you? Unfortunately my university is not the one receiving my EAD card. I’m just worried that if a friend sends it they will open the letter up at customs here in Austria. But I’ll contact my university again asking if they can mail it to me...